# How to use MVC viewBag concept in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am using express js 4.1 along with handlebars template 4.0. When rendering a page I am sending collection of objects from express route.get('/') to handlebar(.hbs) view file. Is there any possibility to the send object like viewbag (similar to MVC) and should access those objects using @viewbag in hbs file? Below code is used to render the hbs file along with collection of 2 objects

```
var gridData =  [
          { Name: 'xxxx', City: 'dddd' },
          { Name: 'yyyy', City: 'rrrr' },
          { Name: 'zzzz', City: 'ssss' }
    ]
resultSet["gridData"] = gridData;
resultSet["newdata"] = [1,2,3];
res.render('user-list',  {viewBag: resultSet});
```

Here I need to use the viewBag as @viewBag.gridData or @viewBag.newdata in hbs to bind these array values. Also, please suggest how to use @HTML helpers and @section ControlsSection{} in hbs file since the express js follows MVC structure.

Comment: Change this line to `res.render('user-list',  {viewBag: resultSet})`

Comment: Yup.. that is fine.. My actual question is how to use HTML helpers and @viewBag in hanblebars.

Comment: You can't use DotNet libraries in NodeJS. You should find the alternative npm packages or better write your own.

Comment: Also, instead of `@`, you should follow `handlebars` syntax when dealing with the json data such as `{{viewBag.gridData}}` something like this.

Comment: I should bind this viewBag.gridData as datasource for a grid. I will bind this datasource in inside the <script></script> tag in the hbs view file. Since i am using it inside the script tag, i am unable to use like this {{viewBag.gridData}}

Comment: In case of array, you should use a syntax like this, `{{#each viewBag.gridData}}
        <li>{{this.Name}}</li>
    {{/each}}`. You can check this link, http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2013/10/using-handlebar-template-for-json-response.html/

Comment: I can able to deal with displaying arrays in hbs file. But I need to bind these arrays to  "Datasource"  property of a grid when rendering the page. Hence I have go for MVC structure and asked how to use it in express js.

Comment: You should go with jQuery data table library then instead of hibernate. Each library and framework are different and you can't use everything in express/ handlebars/other libraries as same as MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `res.render('user-list',  {viewBag: gridData});` I have replaced

```
res.locals.gridData = JSON.stringify(gridData); // To make it global and accessible in hbs view file
res.locals.newdata = newdata; 
res.render('user-list');
```

When rendering 'user-list' page, `dataSource: {{{gridData}}}` will bind the respective datasource in for the grid and this `datasource` is of json type. It works finally!!!